# Is it possible to create just header tip visible bar chart with chart js just like in image

Tags: javascript, jquery, chart.js

[image: Example Geaph Image]

**I want to change bar graph to make it look like the image one, which has only header tip visible not the whole bar, the header has the detail like shown in the image and only the header visible as a line in graph**

```js
var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart");
var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
  type: 'bar',
  data: {
    labels: ["2015-01", "2015-02", "2015-03"],
    datasets: [{
      label: '# of Tomatoes',
      data: [12, 19, 13],
      backgroundColor: [
        'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',
        'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)',
        'rgba(255, 206, 86, 0.2)'
       
      ],
      borderColor: [
        'rgba(255,99,132,1)',
        'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)',
        'rgba(255, 206, 86, 1)'
        
      ],
      borderWidth: 1
    }]
  },
  options: {
    responsive: false,
    scales: {
      xAxes: [{
        ticks: {
          maxRotation: 90,
          minRotation: 80
        }
      }],
      yAxes: [{
        ticks: {
          beginAtZero: true
        }
      }]
    }
  }
});
```

```css
body {
  background-color: #a3d5d3;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="myChart" height="200"></canvas>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.1.6/Chart.js"></script>
```

Comment: Please post your current chart js code with some sample hard-coded data so that others can use to debug the code and provide better solutions.

Comment: https://codepen.io/marshyon/pen/JKJWKY?editors=0110

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want to display a dash for each value, you better choose a [scatter chart](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/charts/scatter.html) and define `dataset.pointStyle` as 'line'. For scatter charts, no `labels` are defined but the data must be passed as objects containing `x` and `y` properties. Your `xAxes` would then have to be defined as a [time cartesian axis](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/axes/cartesian/time.html).

> Note that Chart.js internally uses [Moment.js](https://momentjs.com/) for the functionality of the time axis. Therefore you should use the [bundled version](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/getting-started/installation.html#bundled-build) of Chart.js that includes Moment.js in a single file.

The following code illustrates how it can be done.

```js
var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart");
var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
  type: 'scatter',
  data: {
    datasets: [{
      label: '# of Tomatoes',
      data: [
        { x: "2015-01", y: 12 },
        { x: "2015-02", y: 19 },
        { x: "2015-03", y: 3 },
        { x: "2015-04", y: 5 },
        { x: "2015-05", y: 2 },
        { x: "2015-06", y: 3 },
        { x: "2015-07", y: 20 },
        { x: "2015-08", y: 3 },
        { x: "2015-09", y: 5 },
        { x: "2015-10", y: 6 },
        { x: "2015-11", y: 2 },
        { x: "2015-12", y: 1 }
      ],
      backgroundColor: [
        'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',
        'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)',
        'rgba(255, 206, 86, 0.2)',
        'rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.2)',
        'rgba(153, 102, 255, 0.2)',
        'rgba(255, 159, 64, 0.2)',
        'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',
        'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)',
        'rgba(255, 206, 86, 0.2)',
        'rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.2)',
        'rgba(153, 102, 255, 0.2)',
        'rgba(255, 159, 64, 0.2)'
      ],
      borderColor: [
        'rgba(255,99,132,1)',
        'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)',
        'rgba(255, 206, 86, 1)',
        'rgba(75, 192, 192, 1)',
        'rgba(153, 102, 255, 1)',
        'rgba(255, 159, 64, 1)',
        'rgba(255,99,132,1)',
        'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)',
        'rgba(255, 206, 86, 1)',
        'rgba(75, 192, 192, 1)',
        'rgba(153, 102, 255, 1)',
        'rgba(255, 159, 64, 1)'
      ],
      pointStyle: 'line',
      pointRadius: 10,
      pointHoverRadius: 10
    }]
  },
  options: {
    responsive: false,
    scales: {
      xAxes: [{        
        offset: true,
        type: 'time',
        time: {
          unit: 'month',
          displayFormats: {
            month: 'YYYY-MM'   
          },
          tooltipFormat: 'YYYY-MM'          
        },
        ticks: {
          maxRotation: 90,
          minRotation: 80
        },
        gridLines: {
          offsetGridLines: true
        }
      }],
      yAxes: [{
        ticks: {
          beginAtZero: true
        }
      }]
    }
  }
});
```

```css
body {
  background-color: #a3d5d3;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.9.3/Chart.bundle.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="myChart" height="200"></canvas>
```

Answer (score 0):

If I correctly understand your question, you need **floating bars**, which are officially available since [Chart.js v2.9.0](https://github.com/chartjs/Chart.js/releases/tag/v2.9.0). The feature was merged into [chartjs:master](https://github.com/chartjs/Chart.js) with [pull request #6056](https://github.com/chartjs/Chart.js/pull/6056). Individual bars can now be specified with the syntax `[min, max]`.

```js
var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart");
var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
  type: 'bar',
  data: {
    labels: ["2015-01", "2015-02", "2015-03", "2015-04", "2015-05", "2015-06", "2015-07", "2015-08", "2015-09", "2015-10", "2015-11", "2015-12"],
    datasets: [{
      label: '# of Tomatoes',
      data: [[11,12], [18,19], [2,3], [4,5], [1,2], [2,3], [19,20], [2,3], [4,5], [5,6], [1,2], [0,1]],
      backgroundColor: [
        'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',
        'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)',
        'rgba(255, 206, 86, 0.2)',
        'rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.2)',
        'rgba(153, 102, 255, 0.2)',
        'rgba(255, 159, 64, 0.2)',
        'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',
        'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)',
        'rgba(255, 206, 86, 0.2)',
        'rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.2)',
        'rgba(153, 102, 255, 0.2)',
        'rgba(255, 159, 64, 0.2)'
      ],
      borderColor: [
        'rgba(255,99,132,1)',
        'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)',
        'rgba(255, 206, 86, 1)',
        'rgba(75, 192, 192, 1)',
        'rgba(153, 102, 255, 1)',
        'rgba(255, 159, 64, 1)',
        'rgba(255,99,132,1)',
        'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)',
        'rgba(255, 206, 86, 1)',
        'rgba(75, 192, 192, 1)',
        'rgba(153, 102, 255, 1)',
        'rgba(255, 159, 64, 1)'
      ],
      borderWidth: 1
    }]
  },
  options: {
    responsive: false,
    scales: {
      xAxes: [{
        ticks: {
          maxRotation: 90,
          minRotation: 80
        }
      }],
      yAxes: [{
        ticks: {
          beginAtZero: true
        }
      }]
    }
  }
});
```

```css
body {
  background-color: #a3d5d3;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.9.3/Chart.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="myChart" height="200"></canvas>
```

Comment: this could be helpful but I just want one point which is just starting point, I want to display percentage value which is only one value consider as the start. suppose there is data at 2015-01 is only 12 no start no end just dash at the 12 value.